# Проблема с QML-импортом

Tags: c++, android, qt, qml, qtquick

Привет всем! Решил попробовать сделать приложение для Android в связке QML и C++ и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Имеется класс на C++ - `Mytype`, связываю его с QML с помощью `qmlregistertype`. На десктопе всё собирается и работает нормально (в том числе мой класс `Mytype`). Apk для андроид тоже собирается, запускается на устройстве нормально, но `Mytype` на устройстве не работает. При сборке apk выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: 
>   mytype.

Что это за ошибка и как её исправить, помогите, уже третий день не могу понять. 
Упрощённый пример кода:

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
    #include "mytype.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Mytype>("mytype", 1, 0, "Mytype");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

qml:

```
import mytype 1.0;
    ...
    Mytype {
        id: my_type;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите, что не так  с импортом?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что mytype.h не собирается (если конечно с именами всё в порядке). Может есть какие-то зависимости, не позволяющие проинициализироваться.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю: как mytype.h может не собираеться, если на компе класс Mytype работает отлично... А на андроиде его как-будто просто не существует. Может для андроид нужно как-то по-другому регистрировать c++ класс?

Comment: @Dmitriy_RUS У андроида есть так же куча степеней доступа к тому или иному. Если например класс требует подключение к Интернету, которое ему не предоставили и не предусмотрев это он просто вызывает исключение, вместо того чтобы работать дальше. Как пример.

Comment: Проблема в том, что даже пустой класс при сборке для андроид вызывает аналогичную ошибку: **Warning: QML import could not be resolved in ...**

Comment: Откуда вообще идут корни этого **Warning**???

Comment: Покажите исходный код mytype